# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class KickCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('kick', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    var roleArray = "821849525748498462, 821849524817362994, 825107474775801886, 821849524074709042, 825083476617068594, 826870496544817152, 821849513672179722, 821849511608582225, 821849511080886282";
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => roleArray.includes(role.id))) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`Invalid Permissions`).setColor('#FF0000'));
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) reason = "No reason given";
    const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.mentionedMember.user.tag} was kicked from the server`)
      .setDescription(`Reason: ${reason}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setColor("#00FF00");
    const kickMessageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`__**You were kicked from a server.**__`)
      .setDescription(`
      **Server Name:** ${message.guild.name}
      **Reason:** ${reason}
      **Kicked by:** <@${message.author.id}>
      `)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setColor(`#0000FF`);
```

This is what Code I am using. The issue is at message.mentionedMember.user.tag
It then proceeds to print me a long ass error about user in not defined. I have tried like 10 different ways of formatting and googling and cannot seem to find a fix.

Comment: The `message` object does not have a `mentionedMember` property. Remove the `message` part of your code. You're attempting to use a variable's definition, not an object property's.

Answer (score 0):

While defining the valuable of mentionedMember via const at the beginning, mentionedMember is containing the property of message.member and message does not have a property called mentionedMember, and this is the reason of causing the undefined error. You should replace with this:

```js
. setTitle(`${mentionedMember.user.tag} was kicked from the server`)
```

And this should be working, comment down below if there is other problem.